# Issue with UBA sanitizer casting negative double to unsigned long long on C++

Tags: c++, sanitizer, ubsan

I've been working with C++ and have been utilizing the UBA sanitizer to convert a double to an unsigned long long. However, I've been encountering an issue when the value is negative, which results in the error message: "runtime error: value -2 is outside the range of representable values of type 'long long unsigned int'"

The code is something like this:

```
unsigned long long valueULL = 0;
double value = -2;
valueULL = (unsigned long long)value;
```

I tried to use this cast instead and it doesn't help:

```
valueULL = std::make_unsigned_t<unsigned long long>(value);
```

Is there a way to cast it without encountering this error?

Comment: What is UBA sanitizer? Could you use a usual sanitizer name?

Comment: The sanitizer is The Undefined Behavior Sanitizer - UBSAN.

Comment: Your description is not particularly clear, but I assume `value` has type `double` (and value `2.0`).   Converting a `double` to an integral type has two steps - first, discard any fractional part (truncate toward zero).   From there, if the truncated value cannot be represented using the integral type, behaviour is undefined.   That's what your sanitiser is detecting (since `-2.0` is outside the range any `unsigned` type can represent).   As to what you need to do - that depends on what you expect a conversion of `-2.0` to an unsigned type to produce, and you haven't described that at all.

Comment: Have you tried -2U?

Comment: I edited the code in the question.

Comment: What do you want the result to be?

Comment: There is probably only one reasonable result and "two-step cast" that has been suggested namely `(unsigned long long)(long long)value` will give you that

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you're referring to clang's `-fsanitize=undefined` UBSanitizer.
The sanitizer is correct in this case, and your code really does contain undefined behavior:

> A prvalue of a floating-point type can be converted to a prvalue of an integer type.
> The conversion truncates; that is, the fractional part is discarded.
> **The behavior is undefined if the truncated value cannot be represented in the destination type.**

- [[conv.fpint] §1](https://eel.is/c++draft/conv.fpint#1)

You can fix your undefined behavior with a two-step cast:

```cpp
double value = -2;
auto valueULL = static_cast<unsigned long long>(static_cast<long long>(value));
```

Or alternatively, you could call [`std::llround`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/round):

```cpp
auto valueULL = static_cast<unsigned long long>(std::llround(value));
```

Note: this will produce a very great value, namely `ULLONG_MAX - 2`. If this is what you actually want, then these solutions make sense.
Otherwise, you should listen to the sanitizer and make sure that your `double` doesn't turn negative before converting to `unsigned` types.